# JSONing a Grepped Environment (jq + grep + env)

Tags: grep, environment-variables, jq

I want to get only AWS_ environments variables from the environment and output them into a JSON.
Usually, doing env | grep AWS_ shows me the right env vars, and jq -n env would show the whole env as JSON.

I've tried:

```
jq -n $(env | grep AWS_)
```

and

```
jq -n $(env $(grep AWS_))
```

both without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many options, but since (as you point out) jq has an `env` filter that produces the JSON for you, it would make sense to use it without having to invoke `grep` and then parse the output to convert it to JSON. For example:

```
jq -n 'env | with_entries(select(.key | test("AWS_")))'
```

You might want to change the test to use "^AWS_".